# Android Crashlytics and Gradle 4.10.1 'varient.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' warning

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics-android

Just upgraded to the latest Gradle build and am getting the following warning:

`WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.`

I know it's caused by the fabric plugin because removing `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` from my app's `build.gradle` file removes the error when syncing.

Anyone know when fabric will update their plugin to conform to the new Gradle standard or how to manually change the code? I see exactly the problem, but don't know how or if I can change that line of code within fabric myself.

I don't think it's a functional problem yet, but really annoying to see each time I sync the gradle file.

Comment: Keep an eye on this  issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116408637

Comment: Thanks will do, but should this be a Google issue or simply fabric needing to update their plugin's code? Just like the rest of us had to start changing `compile ...` to  `implementation ...` this past year.

Comment: Nevermind, I see Google is acquiring fabric and firebase docs still say the plugin is necessary for crashlytics, so this is a Google thing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the 1.28.0 release of the gradle plugin

Users should have this in their top-level build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
     // ... repositories, etc. ...
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...other dependencies ...
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
    }
}
```

Other details

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116408637

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198#issuecomment-473435453

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2019